# Удалить столбец QTableWidget по названию заголовка

Tags: c++, qt

Можно ли как-то удалить столбец `QTableWidget` по названию заголовка? 
Использую Qt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (пример нужно адаптировать под свой код):

```
bool removeColumn(const QString& header) {
  for (auto columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns(); ++columnIndex) {
    auto headerItem = horizontalHeaderItem(columnIndex);
    if (headerItem && headerItem->text() == header) {
      removeColumn(columnIndex);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь два этапа:

1) Выяснить номер столбца, который надо удалить,

2) Удалить столбец с заданным номером.

Первое делается так:

С помощью `QTableWidget::horizontalHeaderItem(int column) const` мы можем получить указатель на `QTableWidgetItem`, у которого можем спросить текст. Соответственно, достаточно пробежаться по всем колонкам, чтобы выяснить, какой номер у нужного столбца.

А удаление я бы заменил на выключение (делание невидимым):

```
table.setColumnHidden(idx, true); // здесь idx - номер столбца
```

Но можно воспользоваться и `void QTableWidget::removeColumn(int column) [slot]`